# Is it recommended to create a user portal with customized user experience on Shopify?

Tags: api, shopify, settings

Walked into a project that is using Shopify for customer and inventory management.  The use of the Shopify Users API (able to use user types) has not yet been used, and only simply basic customer details are used.

There is a need for different user types and I would like to customize the user experience based on the logged in user type, i.e. users portal. Part of the `customer` payload includes a custom `data` field, where we can store a user type.

My thoughts are to add logic upon login to customize the experience based on this, however there is a discussion about creating a brand new customized user portal.

Is this a recommended/commonly-used practice on Shopify or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify user api is only used to create/manage staff accounts for shopify plus store , it can only work for private app.

if you want to manage store customers then need to use [customer api](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer) . if you want to change user experience like UI or listing categorization then you can use customer tags like retail or wholesale or premium whatever you want at the time customer registration then after can list products/collections based on customer tagged (for logged in). You can also used [shopify apps](https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=customer%20tag) that can provide feature to categorise customers based on tags

Answer (score 0):

Where are the customers logged in - on Shopify or external site? You can use **customer tags** in both scenarios to customize the experience.

For the former refer to this [Customer object on Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/customer#customer-tags) and for the latter use this [Get Customer API on Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer#show-2019-07)